# Reactnative pod installe error Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `get_default_flags' for #<Pod::Podfile...>

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

im using React Native,  today i run pod install and get this error:
***[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `get_default_flags' for #Pod::Podfile:0x00007f89a2d98d38.***

here is my pod file:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'MyPrj' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )




  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  target 'MyPrjTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

I dont know why this appear, can anyone guide me to solved this? Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

for everyone who  face this problem, just update react-native in package.json to ^0.68.0

Answer (score -1):

Probably you did forgot to run `yarn update` in the root of your project.

Answer (score -2):

On Project root -

- `yarn cache clean` followed by
- `yarn`

command solved this issue for me.

Comment: the problem is change `react native version` does not update `podfile`, which cause the problem, your solution NEVER WORK for this case